# How to create get method that uses String as its search parameter?(asp.net web api C#)

Tags: c#, api

```
// GET: api/Authors/5
[ResponseType(typeof(Author))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAuthor(int id)
{
        Author author = await db.Authors.FindAsync(id);

        if (author == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(author);
}
```

This is normal get method that returns my book author by its ID,but how do i make one that returns author with its name as argument?

This is my `Author` class:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Change `GetAuthor(int id)` to `GetAuthor(string name)`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the name and use [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where) to search the table by the name:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Author))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAuthor(string name)
{
    Author author = await db.Authors.Where(a => a.Name == name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (author == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(author);
}
```

You could theoretically have more than one author with the same name, so be aware of that.

Here, I used [`FirstOrDefaultAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstordefaultasync), which will return the first result, or `null` if one was not found. There are other options:

- [`FirstAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstasync), which will return the first result and throw an exception if nothing is found
- [`SingleAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleasync), which will return the only result and throw an exception if there are either no matching results or more than one
- [`SingleOrDefaultAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleordefaultasync), which will return one result or `null` if none match, or throw an exception if there is more than one
- [`ToListAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync) if you want all the results, regardless of how many there are

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing,how do I test get method with string,do I just type the name(api/Authors/nameOfTheAuthor)?

Comment: No, it would be `api/Authors?name=nameOfTheAuthor`

Comment: Well, it depends.... if you're relying on your default routes, it might be `api/Authors/GetAuthor?name=nameOfTheAuthor`. But you can always change that.

Comment: If you're using Web API, you can read about routing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) (it works a little differently in Web API than in a regular MVC website). I prefer [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) myself, since the route is defined with the action method, so there's no guessing.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The name of one of my authors is "Jane Austen". When i type /api/Authors?name=Jane_Austen in Swagger GET request it says Error 404 not found,which means that method returned null. Why is that?

Comment: I am new in web apis,so sorry if my questions seem dumb

Comment: 404 means you used the wrong route. Try `api/Authors/GetAuthor?name=Jane Austen` (`_` doesn't mean space - either leave the space, or use `+` or `%20`)

Comment: It works with api/Authors?name=Jane Austen. Thanks a lot man,this site is great

Comment: Oh right, you are returning `NotFound()` when it's not found. Just be aware that it'll return a 404 if you happen to use the wrong route too.

Comment: Glad to help :) we all start somewhere.